Early 70s Australian TV series featuring a basement scene with a fire caused by a knocked-over lantern
I'm looking to identify a TV series that:

Was Australian-made
I watched in the early 70s (my father liked it, I didn't)
Aimed at adults, not children
Drama, not comedy
The only concrete thing I remember about it is a scene in which the main characters are in the basement/subfloor of a house and start a fire by knocking over a lantern.
Set in contemporary Australia
Main character was a man, perhaps in some profession, possibly it was a couple.
The title sequence might have included rural scenes


This needs to be [edit]ed with more details to be answerable. Who are these main characters: men. children...? Nothing else about the series in general?

I've added a little more, but I really have very little recollection of the show!
